# Compare two Iqueryables based on a condition

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have two IQueryables A and B. I need to select all the columns from A based on id available in A and B and also more conditions apply on B list. Here I don't need to do a select from B I only need to select from A but based on conditions that apply on B. I tried the below linq query but performance wise it takes atleast 18 sec to load the data which is too long. I'm trying to refactor the linq query but fails to do the filter. Below I've provided my code that was working but takes too long to load.

```
IQueryable<A_LIST> query = ctx.getA();
IQueryable<B_List> parts = ctx.getB();

query = (from q in query
         join s in parts
         on q.LIST_NO equals s.LIST_NO
         where s.TAG == "PART00213" && s.STATUS == "NEW"
         select q).Distinct();
```

Query that did not work

```
query = query.Where(m => parts.Any(x => x.TAG == "PART00213" &&        
&& STATUS == "NEW"));
```

Comment: You simply forgot to add the join condition to `Any`: `&& x.LIST_NO == m.LIST_NO`

Comment: Could you plz provide me where to add that. I tried it throws error

Comment: `query = query.Where(m => parts.Any(x => x.TAG == "PART00213" &&
 x.STATUS == "NEW" && x.LIST_NO == m.LIST_NO));`

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IQueryable<A_LIST> query = ctx.getA();
var partsIds = ctx.getB().Where(s=>s.TAG == "PART00213" && s.STATUS == "NEW").Select(s=>s.LIST_NO);

query = query.Where(q=>partsIds.Contains(q.LIST_NO));
```